# Missing IntelliJ IDEA Grails 3 code scaffolding

Tags: intellij-idea, view, controller, scaffolding, grails-3.1

I've created a Grails 3.1.8 project using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4 and everything works just fine (the project runs and works like a charm).

The problem is that I cannot find **static controller/views scaffolding** feature in the IDE.

I took a look at the following page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/scaffolding.html but can't find such feature (I must say the documentation there is really awful).
You can see an overview of what I see below:

[image: The only similar option is the Generate button, which is obviously not what I want.]

To be specific, I want the equivalent of the following GGTS functionality in IntelliJ:

[image: Desired feature in GGTS]

FYI, I've tried the *dynamic* scaffolding and it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the IntelliJ 2016.2 update (and later) this issue has been resolved and static scaffolding is available.